# How to display string intelligently using Svelte

Tags: svelte

I have just started to learn `Svelte`.
For my first challenge, I would like to implement this.
There are several email addresses to display but if there is not enough space to display the address, I want to trim the text.\

```
<script>
  let parentWidth,
    childWidth,
    recipients = [
      "Tyreek.Stamm@yahoo.com",
      "Cara_Connelly@yahoo.com",
      "Missouri.Langworth@gmail.com",
      "Rashad_King@gmail.com"
    ];

  $: {
    if (parentWidth > 0 && childWidth > 0 && recipients.length > 1) {
      if (childWidth > parentWidth) {
        recipients.pop();
        recipients = [...new Set(recipients)];
        console.log("new recipient", recipients);
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style>
  main {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .parent {
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px dotted;
  }
  .child {
    width: max-content;
  }
</style>

<main>
    <div class="parent" bind:clientWidth={parentWidth}>
    <div class="child" bind:clientWidth={childWidth}>
      {recipients.join(', ')}
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

As you can see from my code, I wanted to remove the addresses until the `child` element is smaller than the `parent` element.
But unfortunately, the `Reactivity statement` was called only one time.
How can I call that logic like `Loop statement`?

Here is my [`CodeSandbox`](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-worker-zdjed5?file=/App.svelte).

Any comments and answers will be appreciated.

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73261518/546730

Answer (score 0):

By setting `recipients` like this, it gets invalidated within the update loop. That means that at the end of the said loop, the dirty state will be cleared and no further update is triggered until some dependency is invalidated again.

This can be worked around by using [`tick`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-tick) for example:

```js
tick().then(() => {
    recipients.pop();
    recipients = recipients;
})
```

There also is an issue with the `clientWidth` bindings: They apparently will not update correctly when the content changes. A better approach would be using a `ResizeObserver` (there is an [issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/7583) suggesting a switch to using that internally).

For a complete example of implementing something like this, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73262304/546730).